# How to write patch file?

Tags: patch

I parsed source code of two programs using parser and compare ASTs. now I have original file and a file containing changes between two programs.

What should I do to write patch file without using patch command on UNIX ? what formats should I use to write my patch file? Is there tool that take my files and create patch file?

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 1):

Write the output of a `diff` between your two files to a patch file and you're golden. You'll need `patch` or a compatible tool to apply it but it is the most common way to create a patch file.

Comment: Patch file has format that shows which lines should be added or deleted. for example  : 1,8c1,4 . so what should I do to create my own patch file without using patch command and with correct format?

Comment: Again, write the output of a `diff` between your two files to a patch file.